# TableCellRenderer get value

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How can I see if the value is an integer == 150 for example.
And if it is, I want to set the foregroundcolor for that cell.
This is my code:

```
class JComponentTableCellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {    


        return (JComponent) value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? And how isn't it working? And no, never return the value in this situation.

Comment: extend default table cell renderer, test the value of the `value` parameter, and then change the color of the super's renderer before returning it.

Comment: [Other dups](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+jtable+tablecellrenderer+background+color&*)